# How do I install a windows service that runs as an administrator without GUI?

Tags: powershell, windows-services, windows-server-2012

If we assume that a service must be run as administrator, is it possible to install it using a command line (sc.exe, powershell - all is available)?

Bonus: Is it possible to do without providing password?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sc.exe config 'servicename-notdisplayname' obj='\Administrator' password='secret'
```

Still no luck avoiding password, as it's required when starting the service.

Comment: If you want to run the service with the built-in Administrator account specifically, you must provide the password.  But if you can run it as local system instead (which has all the same privileges as Administrator and more) no password is needed.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Any idea why all those negative votes?

Comment: Windows questions often seem to attract them, often for no particular reason.  But it may also have been seen as trivial, demonstrating a lack of research.  That's just speculation though.